# How to set PATH only in bash script temporarily?

Tags: bash

PATH can be set temporarily for following commands. Also, PATH can be set in a script, which remains permanently (in that terminal, or session). How can I set PATH that is globally effective in the script but not after the script finishes?

Example:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path1 path1 is valid only for this line
export PATH=$PATH:/path2
path2 is valid for this line
and this line too
I like it

exit

> path2 is still valid after the script finishes
> and when I type commands here manually
> I don't like it
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

it's simply not true.
If you write a script and change the $PATH variable, the change live only in the script:

```
vi test.sh
```

inside the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="$PATH:test"
```

let's test:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/matteo/.local/bin:/home/matteo/bin:./bin:/home/matteo/.local/bin:/home/matteo/bin:./bin

chmod ug+x test
./test 
echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/matteo/.local/bin:/home/matteo/bin:./bin:/home/matteo/.local/bin:/home/matteo/bin:./bin
```

same output. The change is effective only inside the script!

Comment: Well... it seems I'm totally wrong... but then why is `export` in .bashrc permanent? (sorry this might be another question)

Comment: @akai The `.bashrc` file is sourced in the same environment as the shell that is starting up. It's not a script that runs in its own environment.

Comment: How can I make the change for the current terminal session?

Comment: @Royi if you export PATH in terminal, the change lives until the terminal is closed. As mentioned in the original question

Comment: Why is the change only effective inside the script?

Answer (score 11):

I think you are looking for "source" command (linux).

First write you set Path command (or whatelse) in file, like this loadMyEnvironment.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="$PATH:test"
export MESSAGE="Now i am available on the current shell"
```

Now,type in the shell,

```
> source ./loadMyenvironment.sh
```

Now, in current shell you can check that your envs are loaded.

```
> echo $MESSAGE
Now i am available on the current shell
```

hope this helps.

Comment: That helps me a lot! The `source` command is exactly what I'm looking for and I believe many Linux beginners are looking for this! Very much thanks!